# Hide columns/links in the Quick Launch in SharePoint

Tags: quick-launch

So, this is probably fairly easy. But it's been a while since I've been anywhere else than Visual Studio. I want to hide e.g. Tasks, Calendar and Site Pages in the "Quick Launch". Where do i find the option for doing this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbsCu.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is article with everything about quick launch menu and items inside: http://www.endusersharepoint.com/EUSP2010/2010/06/04/navigating-sharepoint-2010-part-2-the-quick-launch/ (...maybe with more information then you need). Do you have enabled Publishing features on your site?

Comment: Yes I've enbaled Publishing features

Comment: So be aware, that you can find Quick launch items in two places, in Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Navigation or at this link http(s)://portal/sc/site/_layouts/quiklnch.aspx. (just go to site settings and rename settings.aspx to quiklnch.aspx in adress) It's a little bit tricky to live with both places.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specifically hide these elements, I'd say you'd have to use some javascript/jquery and hide it that way. But if you want to hide/remove the entire Libraries, Lists etc. you can go to Site Settings > Navigation > Current Navigation --> Mark the sektions and delete. You can at all times add them to the quicklaunch again.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete specific items in quick launch like Calendar and Tasks as:

Site Settings -> Site Libraries and Lists -> Customize "Calendar"/"Tasks" -> Delete this list